# Using MyISAM for reading and InnoDB for writing data

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I read many articles about comparisons of MyISAM and InnoDB from performance point of view and I decided to use MyISAM for reading data and InnoDB for writing data.

I want to use two structure like an image below. Two same (synchronized) databases but different table engines.

[image]

**What is your suggestions about this structure?**
**What are disadvantages of this design?**

Comment: With that design, from a writing performance point of view, won't you be limited to whatever is worse anyway? Plus, one the problem with MyISAM is that writing can lock your whole table. While you're syncing, you might not be able to read at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you ought to share some of your target performance levels. The primary disadvantage in your suggestion is that you get all of the disadvantages of MyISAM (table-level locking and zero crash recovery) and none of the advantages of InnoDB (crash recovery, row-level locking, and transactions). You're adding complexity for literally no benefit. InnoDB's performance is actually quite good when well-tuned and used properly. I run a fleet of machines handling 20k-30k queries per second on average, an aggregate of millions of queries per second, all InnoDB. Performance is not a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help jeremycole

Answer (score 1):

The disadvantage of that design is that you are paying an enormous replication penalty on write, which includes both InnoDB's supposed read penalty and MyISAM's supposed write penalty, for probably quite a small performance benefit on read.